# Fade in and fade out animations

Tags: css

I have looked at this link http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337# for building my code but I can't figure how to make it work nicely.

I'm making trials on my shop, example this URL product page: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/apache/products/boucles-oreilles-plumes-ceremoniales

What I want is this:

When I add to cart or click on "Panier" in header (it means "cart"), 
I want my cart to fade in immediately without any transition

And if I'm leaving these buttons (or mouses over the cart), I want a fade out animation linear 2.5 seconds before it disappears.

Cart button is selected with this code:

```
.header-cart-txt
```

And the cart is selected with this one:

```
.header-cart.invisible
```

As for the add to cart button, I haven't considered it since my theme already make the header cart popup when I click on it

So those are different trials I made:

Trial 1 :

```
.header-cart-txt > .header-cart.invisible {
  transition: visibility 0s linear 1.5s, opacity 1.5s linear !important;
}
.header-cart-txt:hover > .header-cart.invisible {
  transition-delay: 0s !important;
}
```

Trial 2

```
.header-cart-txt > .header-cart.invisible {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2.5s linear !important;
}
.header-cart-txt:hover > .header-cart.invisible {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Trial 3

```
.header-cart.invisible {
  display:none !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2.5s linear !important;
}
.header-cart.invisible:hover {
  display:block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

But I couldn't figure what was not working
I can't display this fade out animation whatever I try.
And I'm unsure of the reasons

Trial 4 is the most interesting, it worked perfectly but for some reason the cart would not display anymore when click on the button ATC and hover on "Panier" button

Trial 4

```
.header-cart.invisible {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 25px !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 1.5s, opacity 1.5s linear !important;
}
.header-cart.invisible:hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity:1 !important;
  transition-delay: 0s !important;
}

.header-cart-txt:hover > .header-cart.invisible {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

#add_to_cart_btn.button:active > .header-cart.invisible {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Any idea that would help?
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it.  (One you find yourself littering your CSS with `!important` rules it's time to take a step back and start over.)

Think of the `transition` rule as meaning "the amount of time it should take to transition to this state" -- if you want it to be immediate in one direction just set it to zero for that state.

jQuery used here only to toggle the classname on and off; the important bit is the CSS.  I've used background color but of course the same applies to any transition:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on')
});
```

```css
button {background-color: #FFF; transition: 2.5s}

button.on {background-color:#00F; transition: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

(The vendor prefixed `-webkit-transition` is effectively obsolete at this point; it's [safe](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) to use the standard `transition`.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited trial 4 that nearly worked, except it would not fade in anymore, and I don't understand why. Any ideas? I would like to use only CSS for it

Comment: You don't need to transition both opacity and visibility. (It's not possible to transition visibility at all, it's a boolean; and you're setting opacity to 1 in several places but never transition it to any other value.) You don't need any transition-delay. You don't need !important on every single rule.     I'm pretty sure all you need here is a simple transition from opacity:0 to opacity:1 with different durations as shown in this answer.